# Getting the values from an array in android

Tags: android

I have a collection of strings and declared the strings individually as arrays using

```
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
```

and called the arrays in the program by using

```
al=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("titles");
```

Now, instead of declaring each of the arrays i have created SongsArray.java like below...

```
public class SongsArray {
private String title;
private String movieName;
private String singerName;
private String imagePath;
private String mediaPath;

public String gettitle() 
{
    return title;
}
public void settitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getmovieName() {
    return movieName;
}
public void setmovieName(String movieName) {
    this.movieName = movieName;
}
public String getsingerName() {
    return singerName;
}
public void setsingerName(String singerName) {
    this.singerName = singerName;
}
public String getimagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}
public void setimagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}
public String getmediaPath() {
    return mediaPath;
}
public void setmediaPath(String mediaPath) {
    this.mediaPath = mediaPath;
}
```

}

Now i want to call the arrays that i have declared. How can i do that??? I want to get values of each string individually...

Comment: Please clarify "calling the arrays". Also, you name your class "SongsArray" (note the use of *Array*), but technically it **is** not an array at all. It looks more like an element which you will put into an array. Consider renaming it to "Song" instead. Or, to be more expressive: "SongMetaData", "SongRepresentation" or something along those lines. This will make code using this class a **lot** more readable.

Comment: I have to display the values of the array in the list view. So, i have to get the values that are stored in the class and display them in the list view. Thats what exactly i have to do...So, please tell me the way in which i can get the values of the strings that are stored in the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ArrayList<String>` and instead use `ArrayList<SongArray>`:

```
List<SongArray> songs = new ArrayList<SongArray>();
songs.add(new SongArray(...);
Toast.makeText(this, songs.get(0).gettitle(), 200).show();
```